# Put image in the center of bottom border with CSS

Tags: html, css

Everything is explained in the title of this post. I'm trying to put an PNG image in the center bottom border of a div element.

```css
.content_block {
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #969696;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.content_block.orange {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FBB03B, #FF9933);
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block orange"></div>
```

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I searched the net for a way to that with CSS, and border-image and stuff, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve the effect of it being exactly in the middle of the border, you will have to **include the border** with the image by inheriting it, and making it invisible. Like this, you can 'calculate' with it.

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnpqrs53/4/) for the effect. In this Fiddle, I've created a pseudo element that has a background-image of a play button.

The CSS that does the trick is this:

```
div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/gray/video-play-3-xxl.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-top: inherit;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

I've placed it to the absolute bottom and 50% from the left. Then with the `transform` property, I shifted it to be centered around these points (50% from the left, and 100% from the top);

Then to make it move along with the border, I inherited only at the top, and made it invisible.

Comment: add the html, as just css (with no explanation of what element to use) is hard to implement. I had to go to jsfiddle to understand it. Maybe try using a Stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: I've edited my answer to be completely understandable without HTML

Answer (score 4):

```css
.content-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
}
.content-block img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; bottom: 0;
  width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
</div>
```

If you have a `relative` positioned parent, you can manipulate the position of an inner child using `position:absolute;`

Comment: Since there's no `img` element in OP's HTML code, I believe (s)he wants to achieve this without modifying the HTML.

Comment: @Gothdo **On purpose.** I didn't use the `:after` not `:before` pseudos cause the OP  clearly used an UI interaction button. Trigger an event on that pseudo element-alone using JS? Impossible (well, possible by  tracking the mouse position coordinates... etc) Using the accepted answer all you can do is listen a click on the huge parent.

Comment: You can speculate, but OP didn't actually said anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Add an img in html

```
<div class="content_block orange">
       <img class='element' src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/form-elements-kit/100/checked-green-rounded-01-128.png'/>
</div>
```

Add this to your css.

```
 .element { width:32px;
                height:33px;
                display:block;
                background-color:grey;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-top:185px;
                border-radius:100%;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, but what happens when you actually need to put an element or something? This is an example!

Comment: If anything, this should be an `img`, not `div`. Semantic **IS** important.

Answer (score -2):

Put an image inside the orange div and add `text-align:center` to the div

```
<div class="content_block orange">
  <img src="" height="30" width="30">
</div>
```

and then set `margin-top` to the img. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnpqrs53/2/)